# OS X getting window size when double clicking

Tags: macos, cocoa

If you double click the top of a window in OS X, it will resize to its previous size.

How do I programmatically trigger this behaviour? In other words, is there a cocoa function that resizes a window to its previous size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for `[myWindow zoom:self]`?

> `- (void)zoom:(id)sender`
>   This action method toggles the size and location of the window between its standard state (provided by the application as the “best” size to display the window’s data) and its user state (a new size and location the user may have set by moving or resizing the window).